# Android Espresso 2.0 with Multidex app empty test suite issue

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric, android-espresso

having real issues trying to run espresso 2.0 with multidex application, i keep on getting an message testing started and then quits and says empty test suite

> ```
>  Success
> ```

```
  Running testsTesting started at 08:56 ...

  Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
  Test running startedFinish
   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport:     'socket'
   Empty test suite.
```

Here is my organisation of my project

[image: Project]

My Test case

```
@LargeTest
 public class MainActivityInstrumentTest
    extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

private MainActivity mActivity;

public MainActivityInstrumentTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    mActivity = getActivity();
}

@SmallTest
public void checkPreconditions() {
    assertThat(mActivity, notNullValue());
    assertThat(getInstrumentation(), notNullValue());
    onView(withId(R.id.txtUsername))
            .perform(typeText("Steve"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}
}


buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
}
}

  allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
 }
```

Here is my gradle build script

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   repositories {
maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com'
}
    }

    android {
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion = buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
}
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 18
    versionName 'beta version 7'
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    applicationId 'com.closr.closr'
    //testPackageName "androidTest.java.com.closr.closr"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    testFunctionalTest true
    testApplicationId "com.closr.closr.test"
    //testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.multidex.MultiDexTestRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src', 'src/main/java', 'src/androidTest/java/', 'src/androidTest', 'src/androidTest/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

     //        androidTest {
       //            setRoot('androidTest')
       //            java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
     //        }

    dexOptions {
        incremental false
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
      }
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        storePassword 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        keyAlias 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
    release {
        storeFile file('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        storePassword 'xxxxxx'
        keyAlias 'xxxxxxxx'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxx'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
   //            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
   //            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { task ->
    options.compilerArgs << "-         AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=com.closr.closr"
}
productFlavors {
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}

afterEvaluate {
  //        tasks.findByName("assembleDebug").dependsOn("testDebugClasses")
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
  }

  dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
///compile 'com.google.android:multidex:0.1'
compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar')
//compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.3'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.1.+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
compile('com.commonsware.cwac:camera-v9:0.6.+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.2.0'
compile project(':libraries:facebook')
compile files('libs/Catalano.Core.jar')
compile files('libs/Catalano.Android.Image.jar')
compile files('libs/Catalano.Math.jar')

//compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    exclude module: 'commons-codec'
}

compile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile('org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'

compile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
compile  ('com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'){
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
compile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest'
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
     //    compile ('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.0'){
    //        exclude module: 'multidex'
    //    }
}
```

Errors in Log cat

```
    03-12 09:02:47.064    4192-4192/com.closr.closr E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.junit.internal.TextListener', referenced from method android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.addListeners
     03-12 09:02:47.064    4192-4192/com.closr.closr E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.junit.runner.JUnitCore', referenced from method android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart
```

Comment: Are there errors in the logcat?

Comment: Please also post the project's dependency tree (`./gradlew -q dependencies --configuration androidTestCompile`) - that might help reveal the problem

Comment: This comment is off topic but you have a lot of dependencies in your gradle file and some of them are repeating itself like `actionbarsherloc` and `appcompat`. As well you're packaging test dependencies into application like `junit` and `robolectric`. I wonder if you have issues during the dexing

Comment: Hey, the solution was just to create a new project in android studio and import everything in and works fine. Its annoying but i spent 2 days trying to figure it out and it took me about 2 hours to import classes etc

Answer (score 3):

To test multidex enabled apps you need a different `testInstrumentationRunner`

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
  ...
  testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
  }
}
```

And with Android Plugin for Gradle versions lower than 1.1, you need to add the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }       
}
```

More info here:

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#testing

Comment: Looks like things have changed, that page now says "Don't use MultiDexTestRunner, which is deprecated; use AndroidJUnitRunner instead."

Answer (score 1):

Rename your test folder from `instrumentTest` to `androidTest`.

Comment: doesn't work, i had to create a new project in android studio due to the upgrading the new version and import classes and it works fine

Comment: If you'd keep folder name instrumentTest it would not work either.